# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord raise exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I use Rails 3.
The Mongoid ORM have [option](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html) "raise_not_found_error: true/false" for switch raise exception for method .find().
The ActiveRecord have similar option? I know that I can use find_by_* for this. But I need another decision for this.

Comment: can you please explain in beef

Comment: I got exeption RecordNotFound. 
What do you mean "beef"?

Comment: Why exactly you don't want to use `find_by_*` finders?

Comment: I have a lot of use .find() in my code. I have not time for check all usages and fixed it. I want turn off raise use option(as in mongoid). I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way i can think of is to monkey patch `ActiveRecord` find

Create a file in `config/initializers` named `active_record_extension.rb`(or any name that makes sense for you)

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find(*args)
    super
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
    return nil
  end
end
```

PS: untested

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure  you can try this  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/